# "invalid peer certificate contents..." while running `slack run` using slack-cli running on deno

Tags: slack-api, deno

I am on MacOS (M1) trying to run `slack run`. When I call the Workflow and submit very simple form, I get error:

```
  Error: exit status 1
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error sending request for url (https://slack.com/api/functions.completeSuccess): error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer
    const resp = await fetch(url, {
                 ^
    at async mainFetch (deno:ext/fetch/26_fetch.js:247:14)
    at async fetch (deno:ext/fetch/26_fetch.js:464:9)
    at async BaseSlackAPIClient.apiCall (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_api@0.0.2/base-client.ts:20:18)
    at async RunFunction (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_runtime@0.5.0/run-function.ts:57:5)
    at async DispatchPayload (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_runtime@0.5.0/dispatch-payload.ts:64:16)
    at async runLocally (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_runtime@0.5.0/local-run-function.ts:29:16)
    at async https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_runtime@0.5.0/local-run-function.ts:50:3
```

Slack version:

```
Using slack v1.16.4
```

Deno version:

```
deno 1.28.3 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.8.3
```

Can anyone help on this please?

I tried to submit workflow form that is supposed to input a message and enrich it and send it back to channel.

Comment: Could be that your network is blocking outgoing requests to deno.land. Are you working with self-signed certificates internally? Or maybe your own certificate authority? It could also be due to the use of HTTP(s) proxies internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy you can set the `HTTP_PROXY` and the `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables.

Or if you need to load a CA from a local pem file you can set the `DENO_CERT` variable

see [Deno Environment Documentation](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.0/getting_started/setup_your_environment#environment-variables)